# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, linux

Estuve cambiando la contraseña de **mysql** para lograr conectar un proyecto que tengo en Java, y me funcionó correctamente. Utilicé esto para cambiar la contraseña de mysql.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'newpassword';
```

Y de hecho ya el proyecto que tengo en Java me funciona bien.

El problema que tengo en este momento es el siguiente: abro la terminal ingreso como usuario root y escribo `mysql` pero me muestra el siguiente error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

Intenté con los siguientes instrucciones:

```
 - mysql
 - mysql -u root 
 - mysqladmin -u root password [mypassword]
```

Pero el problema persiste, Saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que hice fue sencillo.

Debido a que había cambiado la contraseña y no podía conectarme intenté buscar la manera que ingresar a mysql incluyendo el usuario y la contraseña, o que al menos me logre solicitar la contraseña, con la siguiente instrucción funcionó:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Luego de esto va pedir tu contraseña de mysql y listo.

**Nota: Si pruebas con este comando no va funcionar.**

```
mysql -u root -p mypassword
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que tu problema esta relacionado con la existencia del fichero my.cnf en el home de root si es el usuario con el que estas logado en el sistema y que en este fichero en el apartado [client] esta el usuario root y la password anterior así como el socket a la bbdd.